# how to record open html page time and close page time and store in txt,csv file

Tags: javascript, php, html

i want to record duration of date and time of web page open and close., store data in txt file., for ex: start date time , end date time

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var startTime = new Date();        //Start the clock!
window.onbeforeunload = function()        //When the user leaves the page(closes the window/tab, clicks a link)...
{
    var endTime = new Date();        //Get the current time.
    var timeSpent=(endTime - startTime);        //Find out how long it's been.
    alert(timeSpent);        //Pop up a window with the time spent in microseconds.
}
```

Comment: And what have u tried ?

Comment: @iJade i have added the code and i tried that example ., i dont have any specific idea how to do this so i'm referring some ex and trying to get idea from professionals like you., how to get and store data of webpage view duration for analysis

Comment: It seems rude to do an `alert()` on close. I would look into using AJAX.

Comment: Where you want to save data? Saving it on user computer will do you no good so you need to send it via AJAX.

Comment: @mahesh many people on here are not professionals, occasionally you could actually get pretty bad advice.

Comment: @doveyg that one is an example ., i tried.. i'll remove the alert ., no intimation to user and all.i wanted to get open and close time and store data in server in txt or csv

Comment: @Volvox i want to save data in server., i want to get open and close date time store data in server as text file

Comment: @mahesh: AJAX will allow you to save a text file on the server.

Comment: @doveyg i'm don't know about ajax and i'm new to javascript,how to get data from javascript to ajax., pls guide me. if possible provide some example let me study and to it

Comment: Just google it?.. [Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)